# не работает код редиректа !!! ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с этим кодам я понимаю принцип работы, но не могу понять почему не работает глубочайшая вам спасибо за помощь неделю этот код мучаю и не могу разобраться.

Он должен делать ссылку во такую http://yandex.ru

и он не делает редирект по ней

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
    function fu_href(){
    //  перейти по ссылке в текущем окне
    //  document.location.href = "http://www.yandex.ru"
    //   Открыть  урл  в новом окне
    window.open("http://yandex.ru");
    }
    
    /*
        Можно попробовать вариант добавления ссылки в тело HTML документа по
     средствам стандартных методов  библиотеки яваскрипта в  браузера 
    */
    // небольшой ХАРДКОР
    var arr = ["h","t","t","p:","//"]
    var arr_1 = ["W","W","W"]
    var arr_2 = ["."]
    var yandex_arr = ["Y","A","N","D","E","X"]
    var arr_4 = ["r","u"]
    
    var teg_A = document.createElement("A")
        teg_A.setAttribute("href", "#")
    
        teg_A.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ссылка добавленная
     яваскриптом спрятана от поисковых систем"))    
        teg_A.onclick = function(){window.open(arr.concat(arr_1,arr_2,yandex_arr,arr_2,arr_4)
    .join("").toLowerCase()); return false}
    //добавляем тег А с набором параметров, в  тега BODY, последним узлом
        document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].appendChild(teg_A) 
    </script>
    
    <a href="#" onclick="fu_href(); return false">ссылка спрятана от
     поисковых систем</a>
    </br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всплывающее окно блокируется в том случае, если вызов window.open произошёл не в результате действия посетителя (например, события onclick). Т.е. надо

```html
button.onclick = () => {window.open('<сайт>');};
```

Comment: <a href="#" button.onclick=()  {window.open('<fu_href(); return false>');};ссылка спрятана от
     поисковых систем</a>
    </br>

Comment: Я вас прошу, пожалуйста, помогите мне надо чтоб <сайт> был переменной 
 fu_href(); return false

Comment: Заранее вас благодарю

Comment: Если вас не затруднит мая просьба, можете сделать рабочий пример как мне надо исправить код чтоб он заработал.

Comment: Мне кажется я предоставил всю необходимую информацию о вашей проблеме. Дальше дело за вами. Если мой ответ помог вам, пометьте его как правильный.